# I want to access and use my andriod on my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: android, ubuntu, connection, mirroring

Phone: Techno Spark 4

I wanted to ask if there is a way to access my phone via my laptop? Like mirroring its screen and use it completely from the laptop. I searched up the web, and all the guides I found required some sort of interaction with the mobile to set it up. The issue with my phone is that the screen was broken to smithereens, neither the touch would work nor the screen would display (it found itself in an accident). The only indication that it is still working is that the screen does light up when I press the power button. So please let me know if there is any way that I can get access to it, repairing is probably an option but is not feasible for me currently. Thank you very much for any help you drop in and have a great day.

My research so far:

1. To access the screen mirroring I can install the *scrcpy*, but this requires the *USB Debugging* option to be enabled.
2. I can use the phone with a mouse via OTG connector but if I can't see the screen, I cannot navigate.

So if I can somehow just have the screen displayed without any interaction that would involve the touchscreen and the diplay. Then go into the settings using a mouse to enable USB debugging and then get *scrcpy*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy). It's free and open-source.

Comment: According to this guide: [osradar](https://www.osradar.com/how-to-cast-android-screen-in-ubuntu-18-04/)

it requires USB debugging enabled. And I do not remember ever turning it on on that specific phone

Comment: If you haven't enabled it before, `scrcpy` will fail to connect. It worth a try. The other options is AirDroid or some other remote connection apps but all of them require previous installation and setup. I think the most accurate answer is the one you've excluded (repairing the phone).

Comment: Yea, I just gave it a shot, and as I guessed. USB debugging isn't enabled sadly. Thank you for your help though